# How to write code in python to get weather status from mars as provided by MAAS System?(cf.http://marsweather.ingenology.com)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The base url for accessing the REST API is: http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/

Comment: Please read the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on how to ask questions.

Answer (score 3):

Just import requests

```
import requests
```

and then

```
url = "http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/"
values = {}
values['format'] = 'json'
resp = requests.get(url, params=values)
```

SO now you can access all data through resp

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Python `requests` modules as follows:

```
import requests 

resp = requests.get("http://marsweather.ingenology.com/v1/latest/")
issue = resp.json()

for k, v in issue['report'].items():
    print '{:20}  {}'.format(k,v)
```

Giving a weather report as follows:

```
wind_speed            None
abs_humidity          None
atmo_opacity          Sunny
season                Month 2
wind_direction        --
min_temp_fahrenheit   -112.0
sol                   1120
pressure_string       Higher
pressure              900.0
sunset                2015-09-30T22:59:00Z
ls                    48.0
min_temp              -80.0
terrestrial_date      2015-09-30
max_temp_fahrenheit   -11.2
sunrise               2015-09-30T11:12:00Z
max_temp              -24.0
```

Comment: You could just use `resp.json()`, as this manages the conversion for you.

Comment: Thanks, have updated.